# Problem while calling a tkinter project from another tkinter project

Tags: python, tkinter, project

I am trying to make a GUI base login / register program. What i have done is that i have made a file named login and another file named register, in those i have written code for just that particular instance (let say login). In gist , i have programmed each individual windows and now i am not getting desired result when i run it. i run it by making a funtion of those file and importing them into a common file and than run it on button press.

For login.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from functions import *

def login():


    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200+750+400")

    #adding usernme parameters
    username_var = StringVar()
    username_entry = Entry(textvariable=username_var).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
    username_label = Label(text="Username").grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

    #addding password parameters
    password_var = StringVar()
    password_entry = Entry(textvariable=password_var).grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
    password_label = Label(text="Password").grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

    #                adding button to get the values

        #making a function to add in the button
        
    temp_list = []
    def get_values_and_check(value , value2):
        x = value.get()
        y = value2.get()
        temp_list.append(x)
        temp_list.append(y)
        
        #getting the ocrrect username and password from the csv file
        def correct_user_and_password():
            data = only_read_csv("user_info")
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if x in data[i] and y in data[i]:
                    return True
                """else:
                    return False"""
                
        auth_bool = correct_user_and_password()
        if auth_bool == True:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login successfully" , "you've logged in successfully")
            return True
        elif auth_bool == False:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error logging in" , "shame on you you bastard")
            return False
        

    data_button = Button(text = "confirm" , command=lambda : get_values_and_check(username_var , password_var)).grid(row = 2 , column = 1)




    root.mainloop()
```

and for register.py

```
from functions import *
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox

def register():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200+750+400")

    #user parameter
    username_var = StringVar()
    username_entry = Entry(textvariable=username_var).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
    username_label = Label(text="Username").grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

    #addding password parameters
    password_var = StringVar()
    password_entry = Entry(textvariable=password_var).grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
    password_label = Label(text="Password").grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

    password_again_var = StringVar()
    password_again_entry = Entry(textvariable=password_again_var).grid(row = 2 , column = 1)
    password_again_label = Label(text="Password, Again!!").grid(row = 2 , column = 0)

    def authenticate(value , value2 , value3):
        x = value.get()
        y = value2.get()
        z = value3.get()
        temp_data = [ x , y]
        
        if y == z:
            appendrow_csv("user_info" , temp_data)
            messagebox.showinfo("success" , "your Account has been added successfully")
            return True
        elif y!= z:
            messagebox.showerror("Error" , "password dosent match")
            return False
    verify_button = Button(text = "confirm" , command = lambda : authenticate(username_var , password_var , password_again_var)).grid(row = 3 , column = 0)
    
    

    root.mainloop()
    
register()
```

i import these two into another file named home since it is the first page which gives the options of login or register ie:

```
from tkinter import *
from login import *
from register import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200+750+400")


register_button = Button(text="register" , command = register()).grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
login_button = Button(text="login" , command= login()).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that the register file is being run first and not on the button click. everything gets overlayed.

Comment: Comment out both #from functions import *

Comment: register.py", line 30, in authenticate
        appendrow_csv("user_info" , temp_data)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    NameError: name 'appendrow_csv' is not defined

Comment: On main form, you need to write a function for both register and login. Comment out for both `command = register()` and `command= login()`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make a GUI base login / register program

Firstly, start at main form.

Use one `tk()` and `mainloop()` for entirely script.

Avoid using wild card. So use this `import tkinter as tk`, then we use prefix `tk.`

In main for, add two functions for register and login and add both `Button` widget and  keyword for `command`.

Snippet main form:

```
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200+750+400")

def register_now():
    import register
    register.run()

    
def login_now():
    import login
    login.run()

register_button = tk.Button(text="register", command=register_now).grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
login_button = tk.Button(text="login" , command=login_now ).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for main form:

[image]

Secondly, for register.py:

- Comment out `from functions import *`
- Use `Toplevel` for open new window.
- Add root window for tkinter widgets
- add `run()` method to start.

Snippet: for register.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def register():
    root = tk.Toplevel()
    root.title('Register')
    root.geometry("300x200+750+400")

    #user parameter
    username_var = tk.StringVar()
    username_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=username_var).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
    username_label = tk.Label(root, text="Username").grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

    #addding password parameters
    password_var = tk.StringVar()
    password_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=password_var).grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
    password_label = tk.Label(root, text="Password").grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

    password_again_var = tk.StringVar()
    password_again_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=password_again_var).grid(row = 2 , column = 1)
    password_again_label = tk.Label(root, text="Password, Again!!").grid(row = 2 , column = 0)

    def authenticate(value , value2 , value3):
        x = value.get()
        y = value2.get()
        z = value3.get()
        temp_data = [ x , y]
        
        if y == z:
            appendrow_csv("user_info" , temp_data)
            messagebox.showinfo("success" , "your Account has been added successfully")
            return True
        elif y!= z:
            messagebox.showerror("Error" , "password dosent match")
            return False
    verify_button = tk.Button(root, text = "confirm" , command = lambda : authenticate(username_var , password_var , password_again_var)).grid(row = 3 , column = 0)


def run():
    register()
```

Screenshot for register:

[image]

Thirdly:

Same as register.py.

Snippet for login.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
 

def login():


    root = tk.Toplevel()
    root.geometry("200x200+750+400")
    root.title('Login')

    #adding usernme parameters
    username_var = tk.StringVar()
    username_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=username_var).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
    username_label = tk.Label(root, text="Username").grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

    #addding password parameters
    password_var = tk.StringVar()
    password_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=password_var).grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
    password_label = tk.Label(root, text="Password").grid(row = 1 , column = 0)

    #                adding button to get the values

        #making a function to add in the button
        
    temp_list = []
    def get_values_and_check(value , value2):
        x = value.get()
        y = value2.get()
        temp_list.append(x)
        temp_list.append(y)
        
        #getting the ocrrect username and password from the csv file
        def correct_user_and_password():
            data = only_read_csv("user_info")
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if x in data[i] and y in data[i]:
                    return True
                """else:
                    return False"""
                
        auth_bool = correct_user_and_password()
        if auth_bool == True:
            messagebox.showinfo("Login successfully" , "you've logged in successfully")
            return True
        elif auth_bool == False:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error logging in" , "shame on you you bastard")
            return False
        

    data_button = tk.Button(root, text = "confirm" , command=lambda : get_values_and_check(username_var , password_var)).grid(row = 2 , column = 1)

def run():
    login()
```

Screenshot for login.py:

[image]

Comment: @acw1668. I'm not uncertainty. Because of Python 3.12.1.

Comment: It is not related to what version of Python used. The module is created by OP.

Comment: Thank. I will try to remove comment.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the function `run()` as well because it is not necessary.  Just call `login.login()` instead of `login.run()`, for example.

Comment: No!. It is not practical. Always write a function.

Comment: I am new to the tkinter and gui thing. Can yall suggest some videos or channels about the barebones of the working of this whole thing. And can someone explain what am i doing wrong in this????

Comment: Clarification for the "functions" module. It is a module i have made for my ease which has functions for writing csv and binary files and so on.

Comment: Where is functions module?

Comment: I am adding this functions module so that the confusion is clear

Comment: how do i add that file here ?

Comment: Edit in your post.. Not  in an answer, not in comment.